# get parquet file from HDFS with python

Tags: python, hadoop, parquet

I build my own hdfs with windows single cluster, got reference from this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-hadoop-3-2-1-single-node-cluster-on-windows-10-ac258dd48aef)

then I already input my parquet files, but I can't read the file from other computer.

here's my code with python

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq


hdfs_path = "hdfs://10.35.105.35:9820/tampo/oee_tampo.parquet"


fs = pa.hdfs.connect()


table = pq.read_table(hdfs_path, filesystem=fs)


import pandas as pd
df = table.to_pandas()

fs.close()
```

error

```
 1522     # pipe will not close when the child process exits and the
   1523     # ReadFile will hang.
   1524     self._close_pipe_fds(p2cread, p2cwrite,
   1525                          c2pread, c2pwrite,
   1526                          errread, errwrite)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Anyone who can fix this, or is that any other ways to get the parquet file from hdfs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried pandas' `read_parquet()`?

```py
df = pd.read_parquet('hdfs://10.35.105.35:9820/tampo/oee_tampo.parquet')
df
```